# JScrollpane Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Hello: I am using a JScrollpane with JTable. I wanna change the unused area color. 
Please let me know if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

you question is not entirely clear, so playing a bit of guessing game here: I assume you want the JTable to visually fill the complete height of the parent container (which is a JViewport in your case), so the method you are looking for is

```
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true)
```

Comment: Yeah. Thankyou. .setfillsViewportHeight(true); is the statement I required.